# Render json inside another json in my view with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a json that looks like this that I'm reading from my database in Angular:

```
    {"content":"{
  "address": "<p>This is a test</p>",
  "email": "<p><a href='mailto:info@info.com'>info@info.com</a></p>",
  "country": "UK"
    }"}
```

This data is received through:

```
var urlData = $resource('http://info.com/admin/get_page/2');
$scope.Data = urlData.get();
```

In my view there's a place where I need to print just the address and another the email, so I would imagine it should be something like this:

```
<article class="contactInfo-group" ng-bind-html="Data.content">
{{ Data.content.address }}
</article>
```

How could I get the info I want there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<article class="contactInfo-group">
{{ Data.content.address }}
</article>}}
```

json should be:

```
 $scope.data = {"content":
                       {
                       "address": "<p>This is a test</p>",
                       "email": "<p><a href='mailto:info@info.com'>info@info.com</a></p>",
                       "country": "UK"
                      }
                        }
```

see fiddle.
     http://jsfiddle.net/micronyks/9DcXA/4/

Comment: The problem is that urlData.get() saves me a 'Resource' in Data instead of an 'Object' like in your case and it doesn't print anything when using Data.content.address

Comment: Nevermind, I was doing it right, but the backend was serving a wrong JSON -.-